# Show all the labels or customize no of labels that show in gstatic pie chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using gstatic(google charts) library for create a pie chart and I need to add slice labels for all the slices in pie chart. By default, it doesn't show for small slices. How can show the labels for all slices in gstatic pie chart without decreasing the label font size?

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
    var totalOutstandingData = [
        ['Card Product', 'Amount']
    ]
    var totalOutstandingCount = 0;
    var outstandingOptions;

    $.each(jData.totalOutstanding, function (key, value) {
        totalOutstandingData.push([
            key, {v: parseInt(value), f: (parseInt(value) * 100 / parseInt(jData.totalOutstandingSum)).toFixed(2) + "%"}
        ])
        if (value != 0 && value != null) {
            totalOutstandingCount++;
        }
    });

    if (totalOutstandingCount == 0) {
        totalOutstandingData.push(
                ['', {v: 1, f: 'Zero Outstanding'}]
                )
        // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
        outstandingOptions = {'title': 'Total Outstanding', 'width': 1000,
            'height': 400, // show formatted value from the data
            pieSliceText: 'value',
            // default text style is white
            // won't show in center unless change color
            pieSliceTextStyle: {
                color: '#9e9e9e'
            },
            colors: ['transparent'],
            pieSliceBorderColor: '#9e9e9e',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        };
    } else {
        outstandingOptions = {
            'title': 'Total Outstanding',
            'width': 1000,
            'height': 400,                
            'legend': {textStyle: {fontweight: "bold", fontSize: 10}},
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            pieSliceText: 'value',
            sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0.01,
            tooltip: {
                showColorCode: true,
                text: 'value'
            }
        };
    }

    var outstandingChartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(totalOutstandingData);
    var outstandingChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('totalOutstandingPie'));
    outstandingChart.draw(outstandingChartData, outstandingOptions);
}
```

[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysAMF.jpg)

Comment: try option --> `legend: {position: 'labeled'}`